# Select default value in dropdown using SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am facing issue while setting the default value in dropdown box in SAPUI5.

Currently I am using below code :

```
fields : [ new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox("Cities", {
    selectedKey: "City3",
    items : [ new sap.ui.core.ListItem("City1", {
      text : "DE (Germany)"
    }), new sap.ui.core.ListItem("City2", {
      text : "GB (United Kingdom)"
    }), new sap.ui.core.ListItem("City3", {
      text : "IN (India)"
    }), new sap.ui.core.ListItem("City4", {
      text : "US (United States)"
    }) ]
  })
  }) ]
```

But In List box always it shows `DE (Germany)` value but I want to default set other value.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `sap.ui.core.Item`s have a property with the name `key`<sup>[1](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Item.html#constructor)</sup>, that is the one you can reference in the DropdownBox.

```
new sap.ui.core.ListItem("City1", {
    key : "City1",
    text : "DE (Germany)"
})
```

Otherwise you can try using `selectedItemId` instead of `selectedKey`<sup>[2](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.ComboBox.html#constructor)</sup>

Comment: Using selectedItemId its working. You said we can also do the same thing by reference in the DropdownBox. Can you show me example for that?

Answer (score 1):

It will be helpful if you use `key` and `name`

```
 sap.ui.getCore().byId('Cities').setSelectedItemId('YOUR ITEM ID')
```

//if you are using key value pair then its as easy as

```
   sap.ui.getCore().byId('Cities').setSelected('YOUR ITEM ID').setSelectedKey('YOUR KEY VALUE(1/2/3..)')
```